# Finding an array as a substring into another array

Tags: c++, arrays, search

I would like to know if I can find an array `{67,55,65}` into another array `{23,45,67,55,65,66,76,78}`. I am not interested to find individual elements of array, but the array as a whole. I tried some code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int,8> in = {23,45,67,55,65,66,76,78};
    std::array<int,3> sstr = {67,55,65};
   auto it = std::search(in.begin(), in.end(),
                   std::make_boyer_moore_searcher(
                       sstr.begin(), sstr.end()));
    if(it != in.end())
        std::cout << "The string " << sstr << " found at offset "
                  << it - in.begin() << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "The string " << sstr << " not found\n";
}
```

**Edit:** The reason to go with `make_boyer_moore_searcher` is the size of my array, roughly calculating, may be some 10 million. I want an efficient search technique.

I am not sure if my code is supposed to work. I got many errors

> bm.cpp:12:20: error: ‘make_boyer_moore_searcher’ is not a member of ‘std’
>                       std::make_boyer_moore_searcher(
>                       ^
>   bm.cpp:15:19: error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream&&’
>            std::cout << "The string " << re << " found at offset "
>                      ^
>   In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
>                    from bm.cpp:1:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:602:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Tp = std::array]’
>        operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
>        ^
>   bm.cpp:18:19: error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream&&’
>            std::cout << "The string " << re << " not found\n";
>                      ^
>   In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
>                    from bm.cpp:1:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:602:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Tp = std::array]’
>        operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
>        ^

Comment: Have you looked at the [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/boyer_moore_searcher) of that function?

Comment: @Bob__ Thanks for your comment. I had a look at the function and there is an example of string match. I am not sure if that works for an array match. May be i am missing something.

Comment: You should include the right headers and those function belong to `std::experimental` not `std::`. Besides you should implement operator<< for array<int> or use a loop to print out the values ;)

Comment: @AwaitedOne Is there a reason that you're using `make_boyer_moore_searcher`? `search` already does what you want?

Comment: @JonathanMee. I can't afford slow search, as my array in which i am searching is too large and i am sure `make_boyer_moore_searcher` is very fast.   I am not sure what logic `search` use.

Comment: @Bob__ That's the right answer if you feel like typing it up I'd upvote.

Comment: @AwaitedOne Have you benchmarked the default method used by `std::search`? It's only recommended to use specialisations if a need is proven. Also, your proposed alternative is `experimental` only and thus is not guaranteed to exist in all implementations, which has been proven below for yours.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `make_boyer_moore_searcher` you should include the right headers, as explained in the [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/boyer_moore_searcher):

```
#include <experimental/algorithm>
#include <experimental/functional>
```

Then, as those not belongs to `std`, you should call them using:

```
auto it =   std::experimental::search(in.begin(), in.end(),
                 std::experimental::make_boyer_moore_searcher(
                   sstr.begin(), sstr.end()));
```

In your code, also you are trying to use `operator<<` to print out an `std::array` of `int` (which you call string). You can overload it or use a loop instead:

```
for ( int i : sstr ) {
     std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

With your data you should obtain:

```
The string 67 55 65  found at offset 2
```

Comment: Even though it might be obvious, I would mention that all standard library implementations do not implement all of the experimental extensions.

Comment: `bm.cpp:4:34: fatal error: experimental/algorithm: No such file or directory
 #include <experimental/algorithm>
                                  ^
compilation terminated.`

Comment: @AwaitedOne Just as suspected by user2079303. So, either use a different implementation, or don't use an `experimental` feature.

Comment: @AwaitedOne sorry, you may try to update your compiler, but as others stated, it's an experimental feature.

Comment: @user2079303 it might be obvious, but it's always a good idea to remember it.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `make_boyer_moore_searcher` and use just `std::search`. [Test it](http://cpp.sh/26nf)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int,8> in = {23,45,67,55,65,66,76,78};
    std::array<int,3> sstr = {67,55,65};
   auto it = std::search(in.begin(), in.end(), sstr.begin(), sstr.end());
    if(it != in.end())
        std::cout << "The string found at offset "
                  << it - in.begin() << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "The string not found\n";
}
```

**Edit**:

In response to the comment, it is also possible to search a 2d array. In [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) elements are compared using `operator==`. So in this case you can make it work by changing the code to:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 4> in {{ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}, {10,11,12} }};
std::array<std::array<int,3>, 1> sstr = {10,11,12};
...
```

[Test it](http://cpp.sh/3qvli)

Comment: Will it search in a two dimensional array, say i have `std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 4> in { { { {1, 2, 3, 4} }, { {5, 67, 55, 65} }, { {9, 10, 11, 12} } } };`